# Añadir item a Collection en laravel 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

No se como agregar un nuevo item a una Collection de datos obtenida mediante una consulta sql con laravel.

Consulta:

```
$sql = DB::table('barrio')
            ->select('barrio.nombre_barrio', 'barrio.estado', 'barrio.idbarrio')
            ->where('barrio.estado', '=', 0)
            ->where('barrio.nombre_barrio', '=', $this->nombre_barrio)
            ->get();
```

estructura de la Collection:

```
Collection {#545 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#543 ▼
      +"nombre_barrio": "neo"
      +"estado": 0
      +"idbarrio": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

Trato de añadirla utilizando la siguiente línea `$sql->push(['Calle'=>'20']);` , se añade, si pero no es lo que estoy buscando:

```
Collection {#545 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => {#543 ▼
      +"nombre_barrio": "neo"
      +"estado": 0
      +"idbarrio": 5
    }
    1 => array:1 [▼
      "Calle" => "20"
    ]
  ]
}
```

quiero agregarla al indice 0 quedando de la siguiente forma pero no entiendo como hacerlo:

```
0 => {#543 ▼
          +"nombre_barrio": "neo"
          +"estado": 0
          +"idbarrio": 5
          +"Calle":20
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una [colección](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#introduction) se entiende como un arreglo de objetos, en esos casos el método [Push()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-push) añade un objeto más a la colección:

> ### push()
>
> The push method appends an item to the end of the collection:
>
> ```
> $collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4]);
>
> $collection->push(5);
>
> $collection->all();
>
> // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> ```

Ahora por otro lado, según entiendo por tu `query`, tú estás obteniendo un único objeto y a este objeto le quieres añadir un nuevo atributo (en este caso `'Calle'=>'20'`).

Si tú sabes que esa consulta traerá un único elemento puedes hacer lo siguiente con ayuda del método [first()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-first):

```
$barrios = DB::table('barrio')
            ->select('barrio.nombre_barrio', 'barrio.estado', 'barrio.idbarrio')
            ->where('barrio.estado', '=', 0)
            ->where('barrio.nombre_barrio', '=', $this->nombre_barrio)
            ->get();

$barrios->first()->calle = 20;
```

En cambio, si ese query retorna varios objetos y tú quieres añadirle ese atributo a cada uno de los elementos de esa colección, puede utilizar la función [map()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-map):

```
$barrios->map(function($barrio) {
    $barrio->calle = 20;
});
```

Comment: Excelente, gracias por la explicación.

Comment: Buen día, yo tengo una duda en cuanto a la solución, digamos que en vez de agregar el valor absoluto, tengo una variable que esta fuera del map(function($barrio){ }, en este caso como se haría para agregar la variable?

Comment: @PabloEscalante Puedes pasar cualquier variable al contexto de la función anónima por medio de ```use ($var)```. Ejemplo: ```map(function ($barrio) use ($myVar) { $barrio->calle = $myVar; })```. Claro está que utilizando arrow-functions (7.4+) esto ya no es necesario pues las funciones flecha heredan el contexto de la clase.

Comment: gracias, sirvio mucho

Comment: una duda mas, solo para aclarar conceptos, existe la manera de que esta funcionalidad de map vaya agregando diferentes campos dentro de un foreach??

Comment: @PabloEscalante claro, puedes añadir todos los valores que desees. Pd: No necesitas hacer un `foreach`, `map()` de por sí recorre todos los elementos de la colección.

Comment: claro, es que estoy haciendo el foreach para obtener unos valores, despues dentro del map lo agrego, pero al mostrar el dd() de la variable, solo sale un registro nadamas